# Fixed column header width does not match body column widths

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables

The headers don't line up with the column widths. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DyMSb/1/).

[Screenshot](http://s17.postimg.org/dybznay9b/screen.png)

I'm using:

- ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css
- ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css
- datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.js
- datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js
- datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/media/js/FixedColumns.js

Here is the code I'm using:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    var aoColumns = [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null];

    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "150%",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aoColumns": aoColumns       
    } );

    var oFC = new FixedColumns( oTable, {
        "iLeftColumns": 4
    } );

    oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" id="example">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th rowspan="2">Branch</th>
               <th rowspan="2">Object</th>
               <th rowspan="2">Address</th>
               <th rowspan="2">Count</th>
               <th colspan="7">Availability</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th>15</th>
               <th>16</th>
               <th>17</th>
               <th>18</th>
               <th>19</th>
               <th>20</th>
               <th>21</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>United States of America, Washington</td>
               <td>ABC-123</td>
               <td>1514 Amber Pond Highway, Nohead Bottom, Washington, 99205-8224, US, (425) 023-9448</td>
               <td><a href="#">7</a></td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>United States of America, South Dakota</td>
               <td>DEF-456</td>
               <td>7827 Stony Pointe, Sunsweet, South Dakota, 57006-2156, US, (605) 621-7800</td>
               <td><a href="#">7</a></td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>United States of America, Newfoundland</td>
               <td>XYZ-549</td>
               <td>2379 Dewy Pioneer Highlands, Humbug, Newfoundland, A7O-6P5, CA, (709) 217-5115</td>
               <td><a href="#">7</a></td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>United States of America, Washington</td>
               <td>GHI-789</td>
               <td>5842 Easy Bay, Kravaksarak, Washington, 98428-9376, US, (425) 998-1922</td>
               <td><a href="#">7</a></td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
               <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18078539/1545793) answer applies to you.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is caused by the sScrollX-scrollbar, which is adding extra horizontal space to the columns on the right side, and that's why the other ones (without scrollbar) get shorter on the header.

If you comment the sScrollX line, the columns align correctly.

--- UPDATE ---

To fix the widths with js, this would work:

```
// *** FIX WIDTHS ON LEFT SIDE ***
var widths = [];

// first fix widths on tbody ...
$('.DTFC_LeftBodyWrapper thead th').each(
    function(){
        $(this).css('width', $(this).width());
    });

// ... now save the actual widths on array
$('.DTFC_LeftBodyWrapper thead th').each(
    function(){ 
        widths.push($(this).width());
    });

// ... and now update widths on thead
$('.DTFC_LeftHeadWrapper thead th').each(
    function(i, val){
        console.log('i:', i, ', width:',  widths[i]);
        $(this).css('width', widths[i]);
    });
```

I updated a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKDL7/32/)

Note: I changed also `Count` to `Cnt`, because it was too long, on the jsfiddle window, which caused additional width problems.

Comment: I need to first 4 columns are fixed and "Availability" column is scrollable. If I comment the sScrollX line, table will not be scrollable.

Comment: Yes I know. The problem is, the way the width's of the cells are calculated by the FixedColumns-script. With this extra horizontal space it's then "miscalculating" the widths of the cells on the left side. It's probably a bug. But I can't think of any way of fixing this cleanly through pure css. Maybe you can add a scrollbar on the left side too, but fix it somehow? Or "just" modify the js-script.

Comment: In case you havent fixed the problem yet, I think the easiest way would be to re-asign the withs from the first row of the table (underneath the header) to the header cells. So you have again the matching widths between header- and body-cells.

Answer (score 2):

Datatables miscalculates the th widths when they include horizontal padding.

I worked around this by removing my padding from the th, adding a span inside it and then adding the padding to the span.

ie.

```
<style>
th {padding: 0}
th > span {padding: 0 10px}
<style>
```

Change markup like this:

```
<tr>
 <th rowspan="2"><span>Branch</span></th>
 <th rowspan="2"><span>Object</span></th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it by reseting `th`'s margin and padding to zero:

```
th {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Better but not well. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TT9Xh/ and screenshot: http://s13.postimg.org/61w8xbs8n/test.png

Comment: Don't know what `sScrollX` really does, but setting it to a higher value and with my answer before seems to fix it.

Comment: How much higher? I tried 100% -> 190% and there wasnt really a difference for me :/