# Column headers misaligned in JQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is bugging me for few days now... I've researched for solutions and found few but none are working for me...

I've created a tabbed table by following [this](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html) example, and it works. However, in 2nd tab my headers are completely misaligned. Like [this](http://db.tt/qssmDfO8), when it should be like [this](http://db.tt/I7xBuetw).

To note: I have no external CSS on the table, and I have tried using most solutions including [DataTables fixed headers misaligned with columns in wide tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178039/datatables-header-alignment-), and [this one](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11363/column-headers-not-aligned/p1).

This is what I use to initialize both tables.

```
$('table.display').dataTable({
    "sScrollY": "350px",
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": ""
    },
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [-1] }
    ],
    "bScrollAutoCss": false,
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        var index = iDisplayIndexFull + 1;
        $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(index);
        return nRow;
    },
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "aaSorting": [[4, "desc"]]
});
```

And this is for tabs:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    "show": function (event, ui) {
        var oTable = $('div.dataTables_scrollBody>table.display',ui.panel).dataTable();
        if ( oTable.length > 0 ) {
            oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
        }
    }
});
```