# Datatables js Header alignment

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am sorry if It bother someone. Cause I cannot post a comment in topic to ask in this topic

[DataTables fixed headers misaligned with columns in wide tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178039/datatables-header-alignment-issue)

So I post question here.

```
jsfiddle.net/ruslans_uralovs/zDaGk/
```

of Ruslans Uralovs quite good for me but It also kill the sort in the header

Anyone can help me to save the sort in the header?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Please describe the problem affecting you, don't just leave a link to other questions.

Comment: What part of "Anyone can help me to save the sort in the header" do you not understand?

Comment: I redo Like Ruslans Uralovs like the above link. It fix the alignment column, but unfortuately, the sort function cannot work. When never you wanna sort by any column in datatable, it cannot sort