# Jquery DataTable columns order not aligned with fixed headers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery data table. I am facing issue with fixed headers when I load large number of data the tbody and thead are not aligned. Here is my code.

```
 $('#tblProducts').DataTable({
                     "scrollY": 400,
                     "scrollX": true,
                     "paging": false,
                     "fixedColumns": {
                         leftColumns: 1
                     },
                     "searching": false

                });
```

here is the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQmn8.png)

Here is the css I used on the page

```
.dataTable {
        width: 2082.22px !important;
    }

    .dataTables_scrollHeadInner {
        width: 2082.22px !important;
    }

    .thead-th {
        width: 250px !important;
    }

    .thead-th-upc {
        width: 120.6945px !important;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it's not DataTable.net but your CSS theme, css can override your style of headers

Comment: Can you please share your css classes you wrote for it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [datatable jquery - table header width not aligned with body width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237812/datatable-jquery-table-header-width-not-aligned-with-body-width)

Comment: Find the below reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178039/datatables-fixed-headers-misaligned-with-columns-in-wide-tables?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your in page css overwrite your css for datatable. Please remove the following css

```
.dataTable {
        width: 2082.22px !important;
    }

    .dataTables_scrollHeadInner {
        width: 2082.22px !important;
    }

    .thead-th {
        width: 250px !important;
    }

    .thead-th-upc {
        width: 120.6945px !important;
    }
```

May be it helps. For suggestion you need to load less data by using server side pagination. By doing this your application performance will be increase. #HappyCoding

Comment: Thanks alot it helps my columns head are aligned.

Comment: That's great to here.