# datatable jquery - table header width not aligned with body width

Tags: jquery, datatables, alignment

I am using jQuery datatables. When running the application, the header width is not aligned with the body width. But when I click on the header, it is getting aligned with the body width but even then there is some light misalignment. This problem occurs only in IE.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EjFtX)**

This is how it looks when the page gets loaded:

[image]

After clicking on the header:

[image]

My datatable code:

```
$("#rates").dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "sScrollY": "250px",
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
    "aoColumns": [{
            "bSortable": false
        },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]
});
```

`rates` is my table id.
Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle so we can see and test the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I cant create a jsfiddle. There are some DB dependencied in my code.

Comment: could you mock up the table with local data? using the aaData param?

Comment: That is why I have attached the screenshot so that you can guess where it is going wrong.

Comment: cfs : Can you guess from the screenshot? I have also added the datatable code

Comment: It would be much easier to work with your code than to guess from screenshots.

Comment: I have added my html in a jsfiddle in another comment. Could you please check that?

Comment: I am having that issue too. One thing I found it is making separate <table> tag for header and footer.

Comment: I resolved it by replacing "display: none" with "visibility: hidden; height: 0px".
Can you post your CSS?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Found the solution :

Added `table-layout:fixed` to the table. And opened the application in IE mode.

Comment: Do you mean add option or add a name for class attr?

Comment: @JaxSwagger - Just put up a message saying, "This page uses a broken plugin that only works in IE" lmao

Comment: You made my day, thanks a lot ! 
And @Shaggy , just add a browser detection ;)

Comment: worked for me in 2022

Answer (score 108):

#### CAUSE

Most likely your table is hidden initially which prevents jQuery DataTables from calculating column widths.

#### SOLUTION

- If table is in the collapsible element, you need to adjust headers when collapsible element becomes visible.

  For example, for Bootstrap Collapse plugin:

  ```
  $('#myCollapsible').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
     $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
        .columns.adjust();
  });
  ```
- If table is in the tab, you need to adjust headers when tab becomes visible.

  For example, for Bootstrap Tab plugin:

  ```
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
     $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
        .columns.adjust();
  });
  ```

Code above adjusts column widths for all tables on the page. See [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API methods for more information.

#### RESPONSIVE, SCROLLER OR FIXEDCOLUMNS EXTENSIONS

If you're using Responsive, Scroller or FixedColumns extensions, you need to use additional API methods to solve this problem.

- If you're using Responsive extension, you need to call [`responsive.recalc()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc%28%29) API method **in addition** to [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API method. See [Responsive extension – Incorrect breakpoints](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/#example2) example.
- If you're using Scroller extension, you need to call [`scroller.measure()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/scroller.measure%28%29) API method **instead of** [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API method. See [Scroller extension – Incorrect column widths or missing data](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/#example3) example.
- If you're using FixedColumns extension, you need to call [`fixedColumns().relayout()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/fixedColumns%28%29.relayout%28%29) API method **in addition** to [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API method. See [FixedColumns extension – Incorrect column widths](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/#example4) example.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables – Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs) for solutions to the most common problems with columns in jQuery DataTables when table is initially hidden.

Answer (score 72):

I solved this problem by wrapping the "dataTable" Table with a `div` with `overflow:auto`:

```
.dataTables_scroll
{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

and adding this JS after your `dataTable` initialization:

```
jQuery('.dataTable').wrap('<div class="dataTables_scroll" />');
```

Don't use `sScrollX` or `sScrollY`, remove them and add a `div` wrapper yourself which does the same thing.

Comment: you need to add also position:relative otherwise labels in header will stay fixed without following the scrolling of the wrapper.

Comment: I have tried 10+ solution advices but none of them help me except this. Thanks!

Comment: I just disable the sScrollX, sScrollY, then it works

Comment: @LarryCai saved the day. Tried so many things and suggestion and all I had to do was comment out scrolly. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Use these commands

```
$('#rates').DataTable({
        "scrollX": true,
        "sScrollXInner": "100%",
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know sScrollXInner existed.

Answer (score 15):

I fixed, Work for me.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
$('#container').css( 'display', 'block' );
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

Or

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

Reference: https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()

Comment: What type of element is "container"?

Answer (score 9):

When scrolling is enabled in DataTables using scrollX or scrollY parameters, it will split the entire table into two or three individual HTML table elements; the header, the body and, optionally, the footer. This is done in order to provide the ability to scroll the different sections of the DataTable in a cross-browser manner.

In my case I wanted to have horizontal scroll bar because content are scrolling to right. So adding "scrollX" parameter created this issue in some of the pages which are having more columns.

Below code wrap a div around the DataTable with style "overflow as auto". We need to add div when dataTable completed the execution. We can do this as below:

```
$('#DataTableID').DataTable({
  //"scrollX": true,            
  "initComplete": function (settings, json) {  
    $("#DataTableID").wrap("<div style='overflow:auto; width:100%;position:relative;'></div>");            
  },
});
```

If you are using the scrollX,scrollY, scrollXInner or sScrollXInner options - remove them. They may cause problems.

Source: http://sforsuresh.in/datatables-header-body-not-aligned

Comment: This trick fixed my issue. Many thanks!.

Comment: great solution, better than the broken "scrollX" prop

Comment: Best answer ever, I've tried all the answers on this page, but nothing works, except this.

Answer (score 6):

As Gyrocode.com said "Most likely your table is hidden initially which prevents jQuery DataTables from calculating column widths."

I had this problem too and solved it by just init the dataTable after showing the div

For example

```
$('#my_div').show();
$('#my_table').DataTable();
```

Answer (score 6):

issue is data table is called before the data table is drawn on DOM,use set time out before calling data table.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    var table = $('#exampleSummary').removeAttr('width').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         true,
        columnDefs: [
            { width: 200, targets: 0 }
        ],
        fixedColumns: false
    } );
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 6):

do not need to come up with various crutches, table header width not aligned with body,  because  due to the fact that the table did not have enough time to fill in the data for this, do setTimeout

```
   setTimeout(function() {
     //your datatable code 
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks you saved me!

Answer (score 6):

This code will align the header with the body.
`data-table-basic` is the id of the data table I gave.

```
<style>    
    #data-table-basic_wrapper .dataTable, #data-table-basic_wrapper .dataTables_scrollHeadInner {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

After a ton of hours, I just **removed `scrollY`** from `options` and it's working fine

Comment: Mine was breaking after collapsing the side menu bar, but I found calling draw() corrects it.

Comment: mine was problem with `scrollY`. when i removed it, the design problem fixed

Answer (score 4):

None of the above solutions worked for me but I eventually found a solution that did.

My version of this issue was caused by a third-party CSS file that set the 'box-sizing' to a different value. I was able to fix the issue without effecting other elements with the code below:

```
    $table.closest(".dataTables_wrapper").find("*").css("box-sizing","content-box").css("-moz-box-sizing","content-box");
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Yet I have problems with iceweasel (firefox debianized)... works perfectly with chrome

Answer (score 4):

make sure table width is 100%

Then "autoWidth":true

Comment: It is beneficial to provide the exact code with your answer. For javascript/css answers, a JSFiddle is appreciated.

Comment: Table `width: 100%` does nothing when `autoWidth` is true, which sets width in pixels inline, effectively overriding the 100% rule. `autoWidth` will fix the issue alone, but you can not have 100% width tables then, which at least for me is deal breaker.

Comment: interestingly, width 100% solved my issue alone, thanks for pointing to the right direction !!

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#rates").dataTable({
"bPaginate": false,
"sScrollY": "250px",
"bAutoWidth": false,
"bScrollCollapse": true,
"bLengthChange": false,
"bFilter": false,
"sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
"aoColumns": [{
        "bSortable": false
    },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
]}).fnAdjustColumnSizing( false );
```

Try calling the fnAdjustColumSizing(false) to the end of your datatables call. modified code above.

[Discussion on Column sizing issue](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11363/column-headers-not-aligned/p1)

Comment: If that doesn't fix it do you by chance have some surrounding CSS causing the issue. Can you disable your CSS and see if the scrolling and column widths function as expected.

Comment: @MikeRamsey.thanks for the clue fnAdjustColumnSizing( false );

Answer (score 3):

from this answer

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

to

```
setTimeout(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        table.columns.adjust().draw();
    }, 3000);
```

to work!!!!

Comment: the only solution which solve the issue was this answer

Comment: It worked after adding this

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions worked for me, so I'll post my solution: I was loading the table into a hidden div and then showing the div after the table was built. When I showed/unhid the div first and then built the table while the table was visible, it worked.

So DataTables can't size columns in a hidden div, likely because it is getting a column width of 0px on the backend when the table is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap table tag element in a div with overflow auto and position relative. It will work in chrome and IE8.
I've added height 400px in order to keep table size fixed even after reloading data.

```
table = $('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="datat"></table>').appendTo('#candidati').dataTable({
        //"sScrollY": "400px",//NO MORE REQUIRED - SEE wrap BELOW
        //"sScrollX": "100%",//NO MORE REQUIRED - SEE wrap BELOW
        //"bScrollCollapse": true,//NO MORE REQUIRED - SEE wrap BELOW
        //"bScrollAutoCss": true,//NO MORE REQUIRED - SEE wrap BELOW
        "sAjaxSource": "datass.php",
        "aoColumns": colf,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "two_button",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bJQueryUI":true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "table-layout": "fixed",
        "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
            aoData.push({"name": "filters", "value": $.toJSON(getSearchFilters())});//inserisce i filtri
            oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
                "dataType": 'JSON',
                "type": "POST",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback
            });
        },
        "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
            $(nRow).click(function() {
                $(".row_selected").removeClass("row_selected");
                $(this).addClass("row_selected");
                //mostra il detaglio
                showDetail(aData.CandidateID);
            });
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {

        },
        "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']]
}).wrap("<div style='position:relative;overflow:auto;height:400px;'/>"); //correzione per il disallineamento dello header
```

Comment: + 1 as this works, but does not quiet solve the problem as I lose the header column scrolling to the bottom of the table.

Comment: I know. Infact I left datatable in a little project in which I have to keep fixed head plus scrollable tbody. I had to create my own table and a custom js

Answer (score 1):

Use this: Replace your modal name, clear your datatable and load

```
$('#modalCandidateAssessmentDetail').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple css solution:

```
.dataTables_scroll {
    overflow:auto;
    display:inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the Bootstrap tables is rendered first, you should use the **draw** [event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw), and then execute columns.adjust():

```
table.on( 'draw', function () {
    table.columns.adjust();
} );
```

The draw event is executed when the jquery datatable is already rendered.

`columns.adjust()` adjusts the size of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

From linking the answer from Mike Ramsey I eventually found that the table was being initialized before the DOM had loaded.

To fix this I put the initialization function in the following location:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    InitTables();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37279909/3805983). It can be solved with a window scroll event firing one time only.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.
I added the scrollX: true property for the dataTable and it worked.
There is no need to change the CSS for datatable

```
jQuery('#myTable').DataTable({
                            "fixedHeader":true,
                            "scrollY":"450px",
                            "scrollX":true,
                            "paging":   false,
                            "ordering": false,
                            "info":     false,
                            "searching": false,
                            "scrollCollapse": true
                            });
```

Comment: I started having this problem when I added `"scrollX": true`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I just ran into the problem and didn't find a great solution. So, I decided on using some js to get the scrollBody's height, as compared to the tables height. If the scrollBody is smaller than the table, then I increase the tables width by 15px to account for the scrollbar. I set this up on resize event too, so that it works when my container changes sizes:

```
const tableHeight = $('#' + this.options.id).height();
const scrollBodyHeight = $('#' + this.options.id).closest('.dataTables_scrollBody').height();

if (tableHeight > scrollBodyHeight) {
    $('#' + this.options.id).closest('.dataTables_scrollBody').css({
        width: "calc(100% + 15px)",
    })
} else {
    $('#' + this.options.id).closest('.dataTables_scrollBody').css({
        width: "100%",
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$('.DataTables_sort_wrapper').trigger("click");

Comment: Please use the 4-space/tab indentation to make your code formatted like a code block. Probably you should also annotate your code since it's not quite clear how it is related to the problem, where to put it etc. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none of those solutions worked for me. Perhaps, due to the difference in the initialization of our tables, we have different results. It might be possible, that one of those solutions would work for someone. Anyways, wanted to share my solution, just in case someone is still troubled with this issue. It is a bit hackish, though, but it works for me, since I don't change the width of the table later.

After I load the page and click on the header, so that it expands and shows normally, I inspect the table header and record the width of the `.dataTables_scrollHeadInner` div. In my case it is `715px`, for example. Then add that width to css:

```css
.dataTables_scrollHeadInner
{
  width: 715px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was add this:
...

```
initComplete () {
      this.api (). columns (). header (). each ((el, i) => {
          $ (el) .attr ('style', 'min-width: 160px;')
      });
},
```

...

and it look fine.

Answer (score 0):

Gyrocode.com answer to problem was totally correct but his solution will not work in all cases. A more general approach is to add the following outside your document.ready function:

```
$(document).on( 'init.dt', function ( e, settings ) {
    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
    window.setTimeout(function () {
            api.table().columns.adjust().draw();
        },1);
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add fixed width for container table**

**JS:**

```
otableCorreo = $("#indexTablaEnvios").DataTable({                
    "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
        $(otableCorreo.table().container()).addClass("tablaChildren");
    },
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.tablaChildren {
    width: 97%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I would create tables in expandable/collapsible panels. As long as the tables were visible, no problem. But if you collapsed a panel, resized the browser, and then expanded, the problem was there. I fixed it by placing the following in the click function for the panel header, whenever this function expanded the panel:

```
            // recalculate column widths, because they aren't recalculated when the table is hidden'
            $('.homeTable').DataTable()
                .columns.adjust()
                .responsive.recalc();
```

Answer (score 0):

add to your script in page :

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var table = $('#tableId').DataTable();
    $('#container').css( 'display', 'block' );
    table.columns.adjust().draw();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Bootstrap 4, and had added the class `table-sm` to my table.  That messed up the formatting.  Removing that class fixed the problem.

---

If you can't remove that class, I would suspect that adding it via javascript to the headers table would work.  Datatables uses two tables to display a table when `scrollX` is enabled -- one for the header, and one for the body.

Answer (score 0):

I did have this problem for a while and I realised that my table was drawn before it was shown.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="divResults">
    </div>
</div>        

function ShowResults(data) {
    $div.fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $div.html(data);
        // I used to call DataTable() here (there may be multiple tables in data)
        // each header's width was 0 and missaligned with the columns
        // the width woulld resize when I sorted a column or resized the window 
        // $div.find('table').DataTable(options);
        $div.fadeIn('fast', function () {
            Loading(false);
            $div.find('table').DataTable(options); // moved the call here and everything is now dandy!!!
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize there a numerous answers already but I did not see one using the library's title option itself. You can define the data for each column and then define a title property, which will correctly render the headers. In this case, all you need is a table HTML declaration with nothing inside (no th element). There is no need for any additional CSS or JS.

```
itemsTable = $('#itemsTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/getItemData",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
        {data: "itemNumber", title: "Item #" },
        {data: "author", title: "Author" },
        {data: "title", title: "Title" },
        {data: "genre", title: "Genre" },
        {data: "publisher", title: "Publisher" }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers helped me, then I discovered the issue: a stray ***extra*** `fixedHeader` CDN import from a different datatables version.  This didn't kill the fixed header functionality outright, but did prevent it from aligning.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
```

Figured I'd add in case this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Simple css worked for me !

```
.dataTables_scrollHeadInner  {
  width : 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I collapse the right menu on my web page and the table is resized

```
function autoAdjustColumns(table) {
    var container = table.table().container();
    var resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(function () {
        table.columns.adjust();
    });
    resizeObserver.observe(container);
}
 
var table = $('#my-dt').DataTable();
autoAdjustColumns(table)
```

You can create an extension method to simplify it:

```
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register('autoAdjustColumnsOnResize', function () {
    autoAdjustColumns(this);
    return this;
});

$('#my-dt').DataTable().autoAdjustColumnsOnResize();
```

See: [DataTables.net forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/74482)

Answer (score 0):

i just remove `scrollX: true,` from the options and now it is working.

Answer (score -1):

Some simple css on the headers should do this for you.

```
#rates_info, #rates_paginate
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Can't promise this will work just as is because I haven't seen your html but try it and if it doesn't then you can post your html and I'll update it.

Comment: Could you please explain what is that "#rates_info, #rates_paginate"

Comment: They are the id's of the header and footer added by datatables.  I had instances where stretching those out could solve the problem you are encountering.

Answer (score -1):

If your table or div containing the table is hidden initially , first make that div visible and then draw the table