# Jquery datatable header not aligned with body with

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, c#-4.0

I have the main page when a user clicks link button it should open model pop up with student details. All the details in table format. If they want to scroll up the table, the header should stay, only rows should move.

I have done this using **scrollY: true** and **fixed header true** in Jquery. The problem is after enabling this code. header not fixed with body column. If remove scrolly: true it is working fine.

If I search something it is aligned immediately, the same way if I sorting any column then immediately aligned. The main problem is when form loading time it is not aligned with  the header and body

**Main Page**

```
<div class="modal-body">
  @Html.Partial("_SubtoolPage")
</div>
```

**Model Pop up Code**

```
<div>
<div class="panel-body modelpopup-scroll">
  <table id="StudTask" class="table-striped table table-bordered ">
    <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
   <th>Marks</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
   fetch row code.......
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

**Script Code**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var table= $('#StudTask').dataTable({
"fixedHeader": true,
"scrollCollapse": true,
"scrollY": "600px",
"scrollX": "100%",
"paging": false,
"order": [[2, 'asc']]
});
}
</script>
```

I have tried below methods also

```
 //$('#RealTask').DataTable().columns.adjust();
 //$("#RealTask").DataTable().search("ss").draw();
```

and I have referred to this link also:

[Link referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237812/datatable-jquery-table-header-width-not-aligned-with-body-width/46160726)

Everything I have tried but I'm not able to solve. Could you please suggest if you have a better idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with removing those two class "panel-body modelpopup-scroll" from upper DIV.

Hope you fix this issue .If not just call `$(window).trigger('resize');` after table binding.

Like :

```
setTimeout(function(){ $(window).trigger('resize'); }, 500);
```