# Responsive dataTable is not working with Bootstrap 4.3.1

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have an issue with the responsive DataTable Plugin and Boostrap 4.3.1 in this specific scenario:

I have an extra large modal which display a table, this table have 3 collapsed columns with some contact information this work as expected:

[image: Desktop view]

However in mobile display the table dont collapse the other columns as I would expect, and the table is not wraped inside the modal:

[image: Mobile view]

I used the following example at [Datatables.net](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html) and loaded basically the same files with the exception of Bootstrap which is the version 4.3.1 and not the 4.1.3.

My HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" id="modalOpciones" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Opciones:</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table id="tablaDirectorio" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive " style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Apellido</th>
                            <th>Departamento</th>
                            <th>Puesto</th>
                            <th>Fecha Creado</th>
                            <th>Extension</th>
                            <th class="none">Telefono</th>
                            <th class="none">Celular</th>
                            <th class="none">Email</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Apellido</th>
                            <th>Departamento</th>
                            <th>Puesto</th>
                            <th>Fecha Creado</th>
                            <th>Extension</th>
                            <th>Telefono</th>
                            <th>Celular</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
$('#opciones-list').on('click', 'a' ,(e) => {
            $('#modalOpciones').modal('show');
            var tablaEditar=$('#tablaDirectorio').DataTable({
                "destroy": true,
                "responsive":/*{
                    "details": {
                        renderer: function ( api, rowIdx, columns ) {
                            var data = $.map( columns, function ( col, i ) {
                                return col.hidden ?
                                '<tr data-dt-row="'+col.rowIndex+'" data-dt-column="'+col.columnIndex+'">'+
                                '<td>'+col.title+':'+'</td> '+
                                '<td>'+col.data+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>' :
                                '';
                            } ).join('');

                            return data ?$('<table/>').append( data ) :false;
                        }
                    }
                }*/true,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": 'controller/controller.php',
                    "method": 'POST',
                    data:{accion:'getTabla'}
                },
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "directorio"},
                    {"data": "nombres"},
                    {"data": "apellidos"},
                    {"data": "departamento_nombre"},
                    {"data": "puesto"},
                    {"data": "fechacreado"},
                    {"data": "Extension"},
                    {"data": "Telefono"},
                    {"data": "Celular"},
                    {"data": "Email"}
                ],
                "language":idioma_spanol,
                "columnDefs": [
                    {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"}
                ]
            });
        })
```

Hope someone can help me on this one !!
Thanks in advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### CAUSE

Your table is hidden initially which prevents jQuery DataTables from initializing the table correctly.

#### SOLUTION

Use the code below to recalculate column widths of all visible tables once modal becomes visible by using a combination of `columns.adjust()` and `responsive.recalc()` API methods.

```
$('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){
   $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
      .columns.adjust()
      .responsive.recalc();
});
```

You can also adjust single table by using table ID, for example:

```
$('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){
   $('#example').DataTable()
      .columns.adjust()
      .responsive.recalc();
});
```

#### LINKS

- [jQuery DataTables: Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs - Responsive extension – Incorrect breakpoints](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/#example2).
- [Datatable jquery - table header width not aligned with body width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237812/datatable-jquery-table-header-width-not-aligned-with-body-width/46160726)

Comment: I add a setTimeOut to fix the issue but your answer is a better solution thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the table inside a `div`and then give it the attribute `overflow:auto;`