# Adjusting datatables headers to match the body width

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to adjust the width of my header and columns because i plan to show the table on a mobile device. The column definitely got smaller by using the following:

```
columns: [
  { data: 'provinceState', title: 'State', width: '2px' },
  { data: 'countryRegion', title: 'Country', width: '2px' }
]
```

MY JS CODE

```
const getNewCases = async() => {
  const response = await fetch('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily/3-18-2020');
  const data = await response.json();
  let usa = data.filter(val => {
    return val.countryRegion === 'US';
  });
  $('#loadingLabel').hide();
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    data: usa,
    bLengthChange: false,
    bPaginate: false,
    scrollY:        '50vh',
    columns: [
      { data: 'provinceState', title: 'State', width: '2px' },
      { data: 'countryRegion', title: 'Country', width: '2px' }
    ]
  });
};
getNewCases();
```

As you can see in my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0rc4gkx3/) my datatable body has gotten smaller but the headers have not. Is there a proper way to ensure that both get smaller? Am i doing something wrong?

FYI I also tried the accepted answer in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237812/datatable-jquery-table-header-width-not-aligned-with-body-width) Post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it inside a div container like

```
<div class='container'>
  <table id="myTable"></table>
  <div id="loadingLabel">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

And with css you can set the width of the container

```
.container{
   width: 200px;
}
```