# jquery datatable - the table header width not aligned with the body width in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, datatables

I am using jQuery table header in my Laravel-5.8 project

```
          <div class="card-body">
            <div id="accordion">
              <!-- we are adding the .class so bootstrap.js collapse plugin detects it -->
              <div class="card  card-secondary">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                      Internal Respondents
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">

<div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="myTable" class=" table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable datatable-internal">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th width="10">
                        #
                    </th>
                    <th  width="30">
                        Respondent
                    </th>
                    <th  width="20">
                        Department
                    </th>          
                    <th  width="20">
                        Date
                    </th>  
                    <th  width="10">
                        Status
                    </th>                          
                    
                    <th  width="10">
                        &nbsp;
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($skills as $key => $skill)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{$key+1}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{$skill->skill_name ?? '' }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{$skill->description ?? '' }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{$skill->skill_name ?? '' }}
                        </td>
                         <td>
                             {{$skill->description ?? '' }}
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>                            
                                           
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div> 


                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

I am using JQuery databable as shown below.

Javascript

```
<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/datatables-select/js/dataTables.select.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js') }}"></script>  

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        stateSave: true,
    "pageLength": 10,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    });
 });
</script>
```

When I rendered the page, the header width did not align with the body. It appears this way:

[![datatable][1]][1]

How do I make the datatable to automatically align by itself when the page loads?

Thank you.

When I added

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#example1-tab1-dt').DataTable({
      columns: [
         { width: '20%' },
         { width: '20%' },
         { width: '20%' },
         { width: '10%' },
         { width: '15%' },
         { width: '15%' }
      ]
   });

   $('#example1-tab2-dt').DataTable({
      columns: [
         { width: '20%' },
         { width: '20%' },
         { width: '20%' },
         { width: '10%' },
         { width: '15%' },
         { width: '15%' }
      ]
   });
   
   $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
      $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
         .columns.adjust();
   });   
});    
</script>
```

I got this popup:

> DataTables warning: table id=example1-tab1-dt - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCMmB.png

Comment: For [tag:laravel-datatables],  the best way is, use  https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/installation the official laravel datatables library.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43684/header-and-body-alignment-problem) `$($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
   .columns.adjust();` when table becomes visible it aligns with body

Comment: If you use this `style="width : 100%"` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header flexes with the content of your data. as you currently have no data, jquery is unable to calculate the width of the header items.

More information on this other question: [datatable jquery - table header width not aligned with body width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237812/datatable-jquery-table-header-width-not-aligned-with-body-width)

Comment: When followed your instruction. I have updated my code with the new popup - DataTables warning: table id=example1-tab1-dt - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: "Nickvanderwaal - I am using accordion