# datatable - table header width not aligned with body width

Tags: jquery, datatable

I understand that this question has been discussed before but I had tried countless times on fixing the issue and still has no luck.

This is how it looks when the page first loads and I click on the next tab. (set Unpaid tab as active, has no issues)
[image: Before]

This is what happens after I click any position at the column header. It fixes the problem but once reload again, it goes back to square one.
[image: After]

My code:
http://jsfiddle.net/ow6tcz4x/5/

I tried:

```
#1
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
$($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
  .columns.adjust();
});

#2
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
$($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
  .scroller.measure();
});

#3 (table variable as an example)
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

Basically most of the solutions from here [datatable jquery - table header width not aligned with body width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237812/datatable-jquery-table-header-width-not-aligned-with-body-width?page=1&tab=trending#tab-top) and https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/
does not seem to work for me.
Could anyone assist me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your Fiddle does not show the problem you are describing. The Fiddle is missing all of the libraries it needs (jQuery, DataTables, and others - Bootstrap?). Please provide a [mre]. You can provide this directly in your question using a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365), instead of a Fiddle, if you want.

Comment: @andrewJames hi my apologise, I had updated the fiddle cdns and libraries. Please do have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `'shown.bs.tab'` event is not firing because of the selector you are using:

```
'a[data-toggle="tab"]'
```

You can see that is the case by adding a console logging statement to the function. The statement will never be logged. The DataTables `adjust()` function does not get executed.

Change the selector to this:

```
'button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]'
```

So, you will have:

```js
$('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    //console.log( "tab changed!" );
    $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
        .columns.adjust();
});
```

Reference: There is an official Bootstrap 5 example [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#events).

Comment: My god, thank you so much man, you really helped me big time one this one!

Comment: If you are not familiar with it, your browser's inspector is very helpful. Typically (depends on your browser), you ca right-click on one of the tab buttons and choose "inspect". You will see the type of HTML used - and that will allow you to see how that HTML needs to be selected.